# slideTo panel hammer.js

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling, hammer.js

I am working with hammer.js and have five panels that you can swipe through vertically. I also have a side navigation that the user can use to go to a particular panel. My question is, how do I get the side navigation to animate to these panels? The way I have it set up now it just goes directly to the panel without any animation. My code looks like this:

```
$('.what').on('click', function (e) {
    carousel.showPane(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the answer is quite simple

```
$('.what').on('click', function (e) 
{ carousel.showPane(0, true); });
```

that's all you need to do